# React not updating state with setState with Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to create this table shown in image below. When Click on edit button It should change to textfield and pressing on confirm button it should again transform to tr td tags.

[image]

here is my code for the same. I have created Array of objects in which i have id property, name property  and value property. On edit button click, it should change to textfield and on confirm button click the value of textfield should update in array of objects.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import style from "./css/Register.module.css";
import { Table, Button, Icon, TextInput } from "react-materialize";

const ManipulateRegister = () => {
  const [RegisterData, setRegisterData] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "W Register",
      value: 0,
      isEdit: false,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Z Register",
      value: 0,
      isEdit: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "B Register",
      value: 0,
      isEdit: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "C Register",
      value: 0,
      isEdit: false,
    },
  ]);

  const handleRegisterEditBtn = (register) => {
    var datas = RegisterData;
    datas.forEach((data) => {
      if (data.id === register.id) {
        data.isEdit = true;
      }
    });
    console.log(datas);
    setRegisterData(datas);
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.addressWrapper}>
      <div className={style.addressTableWrapper}>
        <Table centered hoverable responsive striped>
          <thead className="orange lighten-2">
            <tr>
              <th data-field="Namee">Register Name</th>
              <th data-field="value">Value</th>
              <th data-field="action">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {RegisterData.map((register) => (
              <tr>
                {register.isEdit ? (
                  <div>
                    <TextInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Value" />
                    <Button small waves style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                    <Button small waves className="red lighten-2">
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <td>{register.name}</td>
                    <td>{register.value}</td>
                    <td>
                      <Button
                        floating
                        icon={<Icon>edit</Icon>}
                        onClick={() => handleRegisterEditBtn(register)}
                      />
                    </td>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      <Button node="button" className="red lighten-1" waves="light">
        Reset
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ManipulateRegister;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You mutating the same reference, you need to render a copy or the component won't render (shallow comparison):

```
const handleRegisterEditBtn = (register) => {
  const datas = RegisterData.map((data) =>
    data.id === register.id ? { ...data, isEdit: true } : data
  );
  setRegisterData(datas);
};
```

Or just change to:

```
setRegisterData([...datas])
```

Comment: I don't understand why this happens even after doing a clone of the variable like:
```let metadataClone = testAssetMetadata;```
Any explanations as to why?

Comment: it is not a "clone" what you describe is an assignment, check if `metadataClone === testAssetMetadata`

Comment: Thank you, doing an object assign worked a charm.
```let metadataClone  = Object.assign({}, testAssetMetadata)```

Comment: you made an error, should be "const datas" (forgot an "s") in your handleRegisterEditBtn

Comment: @Christopher fixed, notice that you can suggest an edit